# Difference between the_content() and get_post()?

Tags: functions, the-content, get-post

I'm working on tweaking a theme and I need to explode the post content to remove some text. The following code is what I am using:

```
$custom_Get_Post_Title = explode('|',get_post()->post_content);
echo "<h4>" . $custom_Get_Post_Title[0] . "</h4>";              
echo "<p>" . $custom_Get_Post_Title[1] . "</p>";
```

Originally, the developer was using the follow code to display the post content, but it was making it hard for me to explode the data.

```
global $post;
setup_postdata($post);
the_content();
```

**MY QUESTION**: What is the difference between these two methods that both retrieve the post content?

Answer (score 8):

`post_content` is a *property* of the [`WP_Post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/) object. `WP_Post` is an object representing the post data from the database. So `post_content` contains the raw content as stored in the database.

[`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) is a template tag that displays the content of the current post. The 'current post' is whatever the global `$post` variable is set to at the time the function is run. The global `$post` variable is normally set within [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) with `while( have_posts() ) : the_post();`.

The crucial difference is that `the_content()` runs the raw content through several filters that prepare it for display. These do things like adding paragraph tags, converting URLs to embeds for things like videos, and converting symbols like quotes to smart quotes etc. Many plugins use this filter as well, for adding things like Share buttons.

So if you just echo the `post_content` it probably won't look right. You can mimic the output of `the_content()` on raw data by applying the `the_content` filter manually. So in your example you would do:

```
$post = get_post();

$split_content = explode( '|', $post->post_content );

echo '<h4>' . $split_content[0] . '</h4>';              
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $split_content[1] );
```

Answer (score 3):

`get_post()` is the same as `global $post`

functions such as `the_content()` can only be used inside of a loop.

the `setup_postdata()` function can be used to make those functions available.

Your top example could be rewritten as follows:

```
gloabl $post;
$custom_Get_Post_Title = explode('|',$post->post_content);
```

or you could do something similar with the bottom example:

```
global $post;
// setup_postdata($post); <- not really needed
$theContent = get_the_content($post->ID); // can used post-id to retrieve specific
$custom_Get_Post_Title = explode('|',get_post()->post_content);
```